# Ruby: Cleanup my code w/ stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, ruby

this is my first ruby script. I'd like to clean it up. How would I go about storing all of the following `nessus_scans.insert()` arguments into a variable to reduce duplicate lines in my code? I'd like to store `:Id => "", :scan_title => ""` etc all into this variable and then just do something like `nessus_scans.insert(myvariable)`. This query is used about 5 times in the code which is why I want to simplify it. Thanks!

```
nessus_scans.insert(:Id => "",
      :scan_title => "#{scan.title}", 
      :hostname => "#{host.hostname}",
      :host_ip => "#{host.ip}",
      :mac_addr => "#{host.mac_addr}",
      :netbios_name => "#{host.netbios_name}",
      :open_ports => "#{host.ports.map(&:inspect).join(', ').tr('"', '')}",
      :operating_system => "#{host.operating_system}",
      :start_time => "#{host.start_time}",
      :stop_time => "#{host.stop_time}",
      :runtime => "#{host.runtime}",
      :cve => "#{event.cve}",
      :cvss_base_Score => "#{event.cvss_base_score}",
      :description => "#{event.description}",
      :family => "#{event.family}",
      :plugin_id => "#{event.plugin_id}",
      :output => "#{event.output}",  
      :event_name => "#{event.name}",
      :patch_publication_date => "#{event.patch_publication_date}",
      :plugin_version => "#{event.plugin_version}",
      :event_port => "#{event.port.number}",
      :risk => "#{event.risk}",
      :see_also => "#{event.see_also}",
      :severity => "#{event.severity.in_words}",
      :solution => "#{event.solution}",
      :synopsis => "#{event.synopsis}",
      :xref => "#{event.xref}",
      :bool_crit => "#{event.critical?}",
      :bool_high => "#{event.high?}", 
      :bool_med => "#{event.medium?}",
      :bool_low => "#{event.low?}",
      :bool_info => "#{event.informational?}")
end # end event.informational?
```

Comment: You don't need to do `"#{var}"`, you can just use `var`.

Comment: I would suggest learning some more about conventions in Ruby. If an object (or returned value of a method) is already a string, you do not need to interpolate it. If it is not, and say an Integer, you can just call `some.method.to_i`. You should not store boolean values as strings, because a string is a "truthy" value (running `false || 'happy'` returns the string).

Comment: I found an error in your code. If you tried to run the query, it will likely fail because you did not properly escape a double-quote inside the string. Here is the before and after: http://pastebin.com/jRVNN0Gs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_data = {

  Id: "",
  scan_title: scan.title, 
  hostname: host.hostname,
  ...

}

nessus_scans.insert(my_data)
```

---

These are all equivalent:

```
def method(arg1, arg2)
  p arg1, arg2
end


method(10, a: 20, b:30)

--output:--
10
{:a=>20, :b=>30}
```

---

```
method(10, {a: 20, b:30})

--output:--
10
{:a=>20, :b=>30}
```

---

```
data = {a: 20, b:30}
number = 10
method 10, data

--output:--
10
{:a=>20, :b=>30}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Didn't know about the bracket trick. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @dobbs, It's called a Hash in ruby.  In a method call, if you list a bunch of key/value pairs as the last argument, then ruby automatically creates a Hash out of them and sends the Hash to the method--which you can do explicitly yourself by using a variable that refers to a Hash.

Comment: @dobbs, See additional examples.